# What's the equivalent of appengine:run for the Java 11 Cloud SDK?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

**tl;dr:** How can I run [this project](https://github.com/KevinWorkman/HappyCoding/tree/gh-pages/examples/google-cloud/google-cloud-example-projects/datastore-hello-world) locally, in a way that Datastore will work? (Zip download link [here](https://downgit.github.io/#/home?url=https://github.com/KevinWorkman/HappyCoding/tree/gh-pages/examples/google-cloud/google-cloud-example-projects/datastore-hello-world).)

I'm migrating a Java 8 project that used App Engine and Datastore over to Java 11.

With Java 8, I used the Cloud SDK-based [App Engine plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-maven) to run the server locally using `mvn appengine:run` and to deploy to the live server using `mvn appengine:deploy`.

I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences) which told me to delete the `appengine-web.xml` file and use `app.yaml` instead..

To deploy to the live server, I can still use `mvn appengine:deploy` and this works fine, with and without Datastore.

To deploy locally, I run `mvn package exec:java`. This works fine for running a basic server without Datastore, but if I add some [example Datastore code](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java), then I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment. Please set a project ID using the builder.
```

I know this is because I don't have a local App Engine environment running. But if I try to run the local server using `mvn appengine:run` then I get this error complaining about the missing `appengine-web.xml` file:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:run (default-cli) on project datastore-hello-world:
Failed to run devappserver: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
C:\Users\kevin\Documents\GitHub\HappyCoding\examples\google-cloud\google-cloud-example-projects\datastore-hello-world\target\datastore-hello-world-1\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml -> [Help 1]
```

So I'm stuck between needing to run `mvn appengine:run` which requires `appengine-web.xml`, and needing to update to Java 11, which says to use `app.yaml` instead of `appengine-web.xml`.

The [Java 11 App Engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally) only say this about running locally:

> To test your application's functionality before deploying, run your application in your local environment with the development tools that you usually use.

The above  [GitHub](https://github.com/KevinWorkman/HappyCoding/tree/gh-pages/examples/google-cloud/google-cloud-example-projects/datastore-hello-world) and [zip](https://downgit.github.io/#/home?url=https://github.com/KevinWorkman/HappyCoding/tree/gh-pages/examples/google-cloud/google-cloud-example-projects/datastore-hello-world) links contain the whole project (5 total files), but in the interest of including my code directly in the question, here are the files that matter the most:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.happycoding</groupId>
  <artifactId>datastore-hello-world</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <properties>
    <!-- App Engine currently supports Java 11 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty.version>9.4.31.v20200723</jetty.version>

    <!-- Project-specific properties -->
    <mainClass>io.happycoding.ServerMain</mainClass>
    <googleCloudProjectId>YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE</googleCloudProjectId>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Java Servlets API -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jetty -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Datastore -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
      <version>1.104.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Copy static resources like html files into the output jar file. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-web-resources</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                ${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/resources
              </outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource><directory>./src/main/webapp</directory></resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Package everything into a single executable jar file. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>shade</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
              <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Exec plugin for deploying the local server. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- App Engine plugin for deploying to the live site. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <projectId>${googleCloudProjectId}</projectId>
          <version>1</version>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**ServerMain.java**

```java
package io.happycoding;

import java.net.URL;
import org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration;

/**
 * Starts up the server, including a DefaultServlet that handles static files,
 * and any servlet classes annotated with the @WebServlet annotation.
 */
public class ServerMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Create a server that listens on port 8080.
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    server.setHandler(webAppContext);

    // Load static content from inside the jar file.
    URL webAppDir =
        ServerMain.class.getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/resources");
    webAppContext.setResourceBase(webAppDir.toURI().toString());

    // Enable annotations so the server sees classes annotated with @WebServlet.
    webAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{ 
      new AnnotationConfiguration(),
      new WebInfConfiguration(), 
    });

    // Look for annotations in the classes directory (dev server) and in the
    // jar file (live server)
    webAppContext.setAttribute(
        "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", 
        ".*/target/classes/|.*\\.jar");

    // Handle static resources, e.g. html files.
    webAppContext.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");

    // Start the server! 
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Server started!");

    // Keep the main thread alive while the server is running.
    server.join();
  }
}
```

**HelloWorldServlet.java**

```java
package io.happycoding.servlets;

import com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Key;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException {

    Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    String kind = "Task";
    // The name/ID for the new entity
    String name = "sampletask1";
    // The Cloud Datastore key for the new entity
    Key taskKey = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind(kind).newKey(name);

    // Prepares the new entity
    Entity task = Entity.newBuilder(taskKey)
        .set("description", "Buy milk")
        .build();

    // Saves the entity
    datastore.put(task);

    System.out.printf("Saved %s: %s%n", task.getKey().getName(), task.getString("description"));

    //Retrieve entity
    Entity retrieved = datastore.get(taskKey);

    response.setContentType("text/html;");
    response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello world!</h1>");
    response.getWriter().println("Retrieved: " + taskKey.getName() + ": " + retrieved.getString("description"));
  }
}
```

**How can I run a Java 11 App Engine server locally so that Datastore works?**

Comment: Did you try to follow [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) about the datastore emulator?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for the reply. I tried following that doc, but I'm getting this error in my servlet: `IllegalArgumentException: Project endpoint "::1:8954/v1/projects/happy-coding-gcloud" must include scheme.`

Comment: Taking a step back, I'm really hoping there's an easier way to run Datastore locally. Java 8 made it very easy without requiring any extra commands outside of running the devserver, so I'm hoping there's something similar with Java 11. My end goal is creating a curriculum for students, so every barrier is very painful.

Comment: It's one of the pain point by migrating from the 1st App Engine generation, with lot of tool included, and the 2nd generation with only a webserver for App Engine, and all the other tools external (Datastore, Scheduler, Task, MemoryStore,...)

Comment: I would suggest you to report this issue with [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) which is intended for tracking reproducible issues and feature requests during product development.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for your suggestion. I was finally able to get it working, and I've posted an answer below. Thanks again for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere)'s suggestion in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445036/whats-the-equivalent-of-appenginerun-for-the-java-11-cloud-sdk#comment112191437_63445036), I tried following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) for manually running Datastore locally.

I ran `gcloud beta emulators datastore start` in one command line, which seemed to run fine, and then I ran `$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)` in another command line, and I got this error:

```sh
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.emulators.datastore.env-init)
Unable to find env.yaml in the data_dir 
[/tmp/tmp.zolNZC8fnr/emulators/datastore]. 
Please ensure you have started the appropriate emulator.
```

I went back to the first command line where I ran Datastore, and I noticed this line in the output:

```sh
Storage: /tmp/tmp.sxkNeaNHxo/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin
```

I copied that directory path into the `data-dir` argument:

```sh
$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init --data-dir=/tmp/tmp.sxkNeaNHxo/emulators/datastore)
```

That command seemed to succeed (with no output) so I ran my local server: `mvn package exec:java`

Finally, this seems to work locally.

To summarize:

**Step 1:** Run this command: `gcloud beta emulators datastore start`

**Step 2:** In the output, find the line that looks like this:

`Storage: /tmp/tmp.sxkNeaNHxo/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin`

Copy the `/tmp/tmp.YOUR_PATH_HERE/emulators/datastore` path.

**Step 3:** In a different command line, run this command, pasting in the path you just copied:

`$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init --data-dir=/tmp/tmp.YOUR_PATH_HERE/emulators/datastore)`

**Step 4:** In that second command line, run your local server: `mvn package exec:java`

This feels pretty convoluted (and undocumented), so I'm still very open to suggestions for how to streamline this. But for now, this at least works.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it all running locally in Java 11 in the same way it all worked for Java 8.
But you need to keep the Legacy Bundled Services:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/services/access#java-11

- So you still have a appengine-web.xml which gcloud coverts to an app.yaml in the staging directory
- You need to add `<app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>` to your appengine-web.xml file.
- I also needed to ensure I had the latest maven gcloud, appengine SDK, and other dependencies in my pom.xml file.